# How do you rough in a floor drain (not shower) for a new concrete slab?

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent, drains

I need to install floor drains in a new building that will have a concrete slab floor. The drains need to be a kind that is trapped and vented. There seems to be many options to choose from for floor drains, each different styles, and I can't find any information on how they get installed in a slab foundation.

How do you rough in a floor drain for a new concrete slab?

Do we install the trap and a pipe sticking up with several inches blocked out around it, then install the actual drain after the pour, and install new concrete from a read-mix bag back into the hole?

Is there a better/easier way/product for doing this when it's new construction? Maybe something where the drain body is taller than it need to be and you can pour around it and cut if off flush and put the grill on top (like with floor electrical boxes)?

If anyone has a link to a video or pictures, I think that would be helpful as well.

Comment: Not my area of expertise, but I’ve seen basement floor drains hooked up and on top of a gravel bed/pipe trench, ready to be poured in with the entire floor pour.  Saw some recently with raised bright orange mud covers.

Comment: This seems easy, but I'd be concerned about cement getting in it.